# Javascript - Need to remove li element when clicked

Tags: javascript

I need some assistance with an assignment I'm working on.  Using JavaScript, I need to use the .target event property in my removeItem() function to remove li elements when they are clicked on. Can anyone help?  My code is below.

```js
  function Post(item) {
      this.item = item;
      this.print = function() {
          var s = this.item;
          return s;
      }
  }
  var postList = [];
  window.onload = init;

  function init() {
      var submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");
      submitButton.onclick = getAddedItem;
  }

  function getAddedItem() {
      var itemInput = document.getElementById("item");
      var item = itemInput.value;
      if (item == null || item == "") {
          alert("Please enter an item");
          return;
      } else {
          var post = new Post(item);
          postList.push(post);
          addPostToList(post);
          var theForm = document.querySelector("form");
          theForm.reset();
      }

      function addPostToList(post) {
          var postList = document.querySelector("ul");
          var li = document.createElement("li");
          li.onclick = removeItem(li);
          postList.appendChild(li);
          li.innerHTML = post.print();
      }
  };

  function removeItem(li) {
      var test = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
      for (i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
          test[i].onclick = function() {
              var test = document.querySelector("li");
              if (test) {
                  var testParent = test.parentElement;
                  testParent.removeChild(test);
              }
          }
      }
}
```

```css
p {
    font-style:italic
}

li:hover {
    cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>
    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <label for="item">Add an item:</label> <input id="item" size="20" type="text"><br>
        <input id="submitButton" type="button" value="Add!">
    </form>

    <ul>
    </ul>

    <p>Click an item to remove it from the list.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to format your code and separate out the HTML and JavaScript sections.  This is pretty unreadable.

Comment: There should be no need to use the event target, using `this` in the handler function should suffice.

Comment: Disagree @CBroe `this` in javascript is a gulag of ambiguity. Whenever possible avoid using `this` (and its almost always possible).

Comment: disagree @GeorgeMauer - if you write js, you should know how `this` works. it's fine to use it where it makes sense, such as in an event handler or constructor function. it's not THAT confusing.

Comment: Yes, but why would you when there's a perfectly reasonable alternative? To save a couple characters? This isn't a hack, it's just making the less ambiguous choice.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer: In this special case I don’t see that much possible ambiguity – although in more general terms, I think I can agree. But then on the other hand, nowadays one would likely not do something like this in vanilla JS anyway, but use some kind of framework – and there access to the element the event occured upon should be standardized anyway (like jQuery’s `$(this)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the part of your code to change (see comments):

```
function addPostToList(post) {
    var postList = document.querySelector("ul");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    //Don't apply removeItem here. Just give the function name
    //The event will be passed to removeItem
    li.onclick = removeItem;
    postList.appendChild(li);
    li.innerHTML = post.print();
}


function removeItem(e) {    
    e.target.parentElement.removeChild(e.target);
}
```

Here's a full JSBin: http://jsbin.com/mivonanoga/1/