# How to use removeChild method?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const toDoForm = document.querySelector(".todo__form"),
      toDoInput = document.querySelector(".todo__input");
      toDoList = document.querySelector("li");

let toDoArray = [];

function addToDoList() {
  toDoForm.addEventListener('submit', event => {
    toDoArray.push(toDoInput.value);
    toDoList.innerHTML += `<ul>${toDoArray[toDoArray.length-1]}</ul>`;
    event.preventDefault();
    toDoInput.value = "";
  });
}

function clearList() {
  const toDoUl = document.querySelector("ul");
  toDoForm.addEventListener('click', event => {
    toDoArray = [];
    toDoUl.parentNode.removeChild(toDoUl);
  });
}

function init() {
  addToDoList();
  clearList();
}

init();
```

```html
<h1>To-Do List</h1>

<div class="todo">
  <form class="todo__form">
    <input class="todo__input" type="text">
    <input class="todo__submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input class="todo__clear" type="button" value="Clear">
  </form>
</div>

<div class="todo-list">
  <li></li>
</div>
```

I'm making a to-do list with javascript and i tried to use removeChild method to clear to-do list but when i run the code, it keeps getting an error like this -> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null at HTMLFormElement. How can i solve it?

Comment: `<li>` is invalid child of `<div>`

Comment: Just edited your question code to a live stackoverflow code version and noticed you have a semi-colon at the end of the `toDoInput` var, i've not changed your code in anyway to avoid confusion in answers but worth addressing this in your question code and production/staging code to avoid console javascript errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I thought you want remove one item at a time, then I made some changes which may be useful but you if you don't need it, you could remove delete function.

For adding an item, you enter a job name, for example 'Job1' an then press "Submit" button.

For deleting an item, you enter a job name, for example 'Job1' an then press "Delete" button.

Press 'Clear' to clear all items.

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    let toDoArray = [];
    let toDoForm;
    window.onload = () => { 
        toDoForm = document.querySelector(".todo__form"),
        toDoInput = document.querySelector(".todo__input");
        toDoList = document.querySelector("ul");
        clearButton = document.querySelector(".todo__clear");
        deleteButton = document.querySelector(".todo__delete");
        
        init();
    };
    function addToDoList() {
        toDoForm.addEventListener('submit', event => {
            toDoList.innerHTML += `<li>${toDoInput.value}</li>`;
            event.preventDefault();
            toDoInput.value = "";
        });
    }

    function deleteItem() {
        deleteButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
            const toDoUl = document.querySelector("ul");
            let allLi = document.querySelectorAll('li');
            allLi.forEach(li => {
                if (li.innerHTML === toDoInput.value)
                    toDoUl.removeChild(li);
            });
            toDoInput.value = "";
        });
    }

    function clearList() {
        clearButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
            const toDoUl = document.querySelector("ul");
            toDoUl.innerHTML = '';
        });
    }

    function init() {
        addToDoList();
        deleteItem();
        clearList();
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <h1>To-Do List</h1>
    <div class="todo">
        <form class="todo__form">
            <input class="todo__input" type="text">
            <input class="todo__submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
            <input class="todo__delete" type="button" value="Delete">
            <input class="todo__clear" type="button" value="Clear">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="todo-list">
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
    <script src="todo.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

The query `document.querySelector("ul");` is returning `undefined` because there is no `ul` element in the HTML. Try changing the `div` to `ul` tag

```
    <ul class="todo-list">
        <li></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: @YoonKim, take a look on [Vahid answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65535434/3938676). He did some other adjustments

Comment: @YoonKim, by the way, I suggest using `toDoUl.innerHTML = '';` to clear the options instead `removeChild`

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to change `<li></li>` to `<ul></ul>`. You can get help from [w3school link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp).
There is a StackOverflow answer about this issue [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911985/javascript-need-to-remove-li-element-when-clicked). You can check that.